# How to launch Angular 2 application without ANY server

Tags: angular

I have a simple Angular 2 project, but I don't want to use later with npm. Do you know any decision to start a project in this way:

- compile all of *.ts files
- copy compiled js-files to another folder (not related with npm or node)
- open an app, using, for example, index.html. just open an index, and all app should works.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the previous answer, you're going to need a server. Luckily, there's this thing called grunt that can make it easy for you:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-serve
```

It will start a local web server with minimal configuration required. (For this however, you will also need npm).

All you need to do later is call grunt-serve and it will fire it up for you. You can even configure it to reload itself upon code change.

It does not particularly matter what you will use in the end (node or any other frameworks for API's), but for development this will serve its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

i followed this guide.
for me works perfectly.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/D9-Wh0NjMSY

Answer (score -1):

That probaly won't work. Browser security contraints will block loading stuff from disk. For Chrome (don't know about other browsers) there are command line arguments to disable these security constraints but it's discouraged to use them.